# Render index.html in Artifactory, instead of downloading it as an attachment

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to set HTML files to be rendered in the browser, instead of downloading them as attachments? We would like to host generated documentation in Artifactory. Right now the structure can be browsed, but all files have the 'Content-Disposition: attachment' header which tell the browser to save the index.html files as files, instead of rendering them.

We are using Artifactory cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You should be enabling the content browsing in the Artifactory repository. More information can be found here in this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-OtherSettings). Basically, you should check the "Allow content browsing" in the repositories Advanced settings. This feature is not supported for Free Tier subscriptions.

Comment: The description of this feature is:

'When set, allows Artifactory users to browse the internal contents of archives (for example, browsing specific Javadoc files from within a Javadoc archive).'

This works, i.e. archive contents can be seen, but this does not affect the ability to render HTML files, instead of downloading them.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer to this question. Changing the parameter does not change the way the browser handles html files.

Comment: Toni, you want to see the HTML content from Artifactory itself without downloading them? If so, the answer is sufficient enough as I'm able to confirm it. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. Also what is the Artifactory version you use?

Comment: Hmm... Has something changed, as index.html files are indeed rendered now? The next problem is that the documentation we generate uses html frames, and the Content Security Policy set by Artifactory denies that: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () Refused to frame 'https://XYZartifacts.jfrog.io/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'". We are on Artifactory Cloud, with 'Pro Team' license level.

Comment: We finally have a working system. The master of our documentation data is in the Artifactory cloud, and in the company intranet we have a self-hosted Artifactory OSS 6.12.2 rev 61202900 (yes, I know this is ancient). The self-hosted Artifactory serves the cloud repo as a remote repository, and the native browser on that one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to save people wasting their time on an issue I came across.

For self-hosted instances of Artifactory, anonymous HTML rendering is not currently possible. You *must* be logged in for Artifactory to render the HTML when the "Allow content browsing" option is enabled for a repository. If you're not logged in the index.html will simply be downloaded by the browser instead.